# How to make 3D Texture Mapping for an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, 3d, patterns, texture

Let's say I have an image like this:

[image]

and I want to make a map or something that would allow me to apply different patterns to make images like the following:

[image]

.So I have a map and I could easily apply pattern to make images with different patterns.
How should I make that map ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Smart Object of your pattern/image (the orange and grey stripes)
2. Duplicate your object(<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) as many times as there are 3D faces to work on
3. For each object/layer, use the transform tools (torsion, free transform) or use the new perspective tools

If you change the content in your Smart Object, all the face will change accordingly.

PS. If you create a Smart Object directly from a vector image copy/pasted from Illustrator, you must create a Smart Object of the Smart Object ;-)

Comment: @jcbaudot thanks for your reply.Could you explain it in more detail and steps ,please?.I'm a web developer and I don't know much about phohtoshop.

Comment: Here is a quick and dirty tutorial I've just made. http://quick.as/vkbyhn0e

Comment: @omid Is it help you ?

Comment: @jcbaudot .Sorry ,I just saw your comment.Thank you very much